# Get time zone information from a date in nodeJS or momentJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs, moment-timezone

We have a current time called 11:10 PM as the string value. We will create a date object with this time. Now from this date can we get the timezone for this date value?

We are expecting the timezone like Asia/Kolkata, etc. Is it possible to get this value in NodeJS/MomentJS

Comment: "11:10PM" has no timezone information in it - you can only get the local system timezone - is that what you need?

Comment: @JaromandaX We need the user's time zone from their current time entered. In the above example, users enter 11:00 PM. Is it possible to get this? We are not dependent on the user's browser information.

Comment: by "local timezone" I mean local to where your code is running ... if it's running in a users browser then the "local timezone" is the users timezone ... so, yeah, the answer below, except running that code in the users browser, not nodejs, will give you the timezone info - note: not sure why the code below is loading the no longer maintained `moment.js` - it's not needed at all for `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone`

Comment: but, from what you're saying, if a browser sends the string "11:10PM" to your server running nodejs, then you have absolutely no way of knowing the timezone ... your frontend code will need to send that along with that time string

Answer (score 0):

You can get the timezone of the machine running the code, using [Intl.DateTime.resolvedOptions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/resolvedOptions)

If you run this in Node.js you'll get the server timezone, any client running the code in a browser will see their timezone.

```js
// Using Intl
console.log('Timezone: ', Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.30.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-hUhvpC5f8cgc04OZb55j0KNGh4eh7dLxd/dPSJ5VyzqDWxsayYbojWyl5Tkcgrmb/RVKCRJI1jNlRbVP4WWC4w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```